# warning of printf format not suitable for a variable of type uint32_t 

Tags: c

I just learned about C, and
I know this is a basic question, but I just can not figure out how I can solve this. For instance, I have a line of

```
printf("value :%d\n",var.value);
```

the format does not suit, as it shows error below

*format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘uint32_t *'

I have already checked at this reference of cplusplus : [cplusplus print ref](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/)

but it does not explicitly state how to print the value with the type is uint32_t * (likewise uint16_t).

Any explanation will very appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you use "u" instead of "d"?

Comment: The real question is: why are you using `uint32_t` in the first place? Do you need an explicit range of 0 to 2147483647 and a range of 0 to [SOMETHING_LARGEISH] does not suit your requirements?

Comment: @pmg: what would you suggest as "SOMETHING_LARGISH"? `unsigned long`? That might well be 64 bits on common platforms, so I'd pause before putting it in a structure I'll have a lot of (by "a lot", I mean millions).

Comment: My suggestion is more along the lines of not abusing the C99 fixed width types: for some problems they are handy (a godsend, I'd say), for other problems they aren't needed (fixed-width types were never used between 1989 and 1999 in fact). *SOMETHING_LARGISH could be UCHAR_MAX (255 or more) for OP needs*

Comment: @pmg: I'm not asking what you suggest *not* doing, I'm asking what one *should* do :-) In a hypothetical situation where I believe that 65535 is not large enough for my purposes, but 4G is, what type should I use? For max pedantry, `uint_least32_t`, but only because `uint32_t` is (just barely) optional. The only reason this "wasn't needed" prior to 1999 was that everyone who worried about this stuff could name their own type, and have a "porting header" to map it to something suitable. Now, for many purposes `<stdint.h>` replaces that porting header. This is a tool to use, not an "abuse".

Comment: But I agree, if 255 is large enough then there's no reason not to use either `unsigned char` (if space matters) or `unsigned int` (if it doesn't). My experience has been that 255 is rarely large enough for anything, and 64k is pretty smallish, hence my fear of `int`.

Comment: @Steve: +1 for the "[fixed-width types are] a tool to use, not an abuse". I have criticized the `uint32_t` too soon. I apologize to @heike and the community.

Comment: And once you start working on microproessors (arm,avr,etc) it's the only sort of types you usually use and should use. You might also find that when porting code between different compilers or even different cpu types the int/long/float/double types all change their meaning.
If I am not mistaken such a thing just shakes through the Arduino developers, they changed from AVR to ARM and suddenly int changed to 4 bytes, suddenly double changed to 8 bytes. Programmers who used types like OP had a much easier life.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You were trying to print a pointer to an uint32_t as an int. 
You have to do two things:

1. dereference the pointer so you can print the uint32_t and not the pointer.
2. use the correct printtf format specifier

The correct way to format an uint32_t is to use the macro `PRIu32` , which expands to the format character as a string.

That is, you do

```
printf("%"PRIu32"\n", *var.value);
```

You're probably on a common platform where an unsigned int is the same as uint32_t, in which case you could just do:

```
printf("%u\n", *var.value);
```

(note, %u instead of your code that used %d , %u is for an unsigned int, while %d is for a signed int)

Comment: I did not know that - does `%u` present any problems here?

Comment: @Steve Townsend: `"%u"` always fetches an `unsigned int` from the stack, `"%"PRIu32` always a `uint32_t`. The width of an `unsigned int` may vary from platform to platform, and might or might not be equal to the width of an `uint32_t`. So, `"%u"` doesn't present any problems **if** the width of the two types is identical... do you feel lucky today?

Comment: @nos: Or bigger. Either way, you just trashed the stack.

Comment: @DevSolar - yes, I feel lucky I do all my coding in C++ not C

Comment: @DevSolar no, smaller integers passed in to variable argument function are promoted to (unsigned) int. So if an int was bigger, it'd mean an uint32_t is smaller, and it would then be promoted and there would be no problem. It is only a problem where uint32_t is bigger than an int.

Comment: Note that you need to `#include <inttypes.h>` to use `PRIu32` and similar macros.  Take a look at that header sometime, if you're already using `uint32_t` for portable code, you should be using the `printf` format specifiers from `inttypes.h` as well.

Comment: @DevSolar - that's true but I would **never** use it in C++ code, why go through this type of thinking on every `printf` usage when there's a type-safe alternative?

Answer (score 5):

If you want the pointer use `%p`,

```
printf("value :%p\n",var.value);
```

If you want the dereferenced `unsigned int` value use

```
printf("value :%u\n",*(var.value));
```

This assumes that the `value` field in `var` is actually a pointer to `uint32_t` - that's what your warning text implies.

It's nice that you get a warning here - `printf` is not type-safe, so frequently misuse of the API just results in a sudden runtime malfunction (eg. crash or worse, undetected memory corruption).